# Django Unable to add WYSIWYG

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement WYSIWYG on my page with this link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adding-wysiwyg-editor-to-django-project/
I am currently at point 5, when they want me to add below:

```
# add condition in django urls file
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

but when I added above, I got below error message

```
File "C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\my_site\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
  File "C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\blog\urls.py", line 16, in <module>
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
NameError: name 'static' is not defined
```

I am attaching urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),

    ]
# to jest dla wysiwyg
  # add condition in django urls file

from django.conf import settings


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Do you know why I am getting pasted error message?

Comment: I think you need to import static like `from django.conf.urls.static import static`

Comment: Seems you were first with comment and that helped me.  But not sure if this is important for you but I cannot accept your comment as you added it as "Add a comment" option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an import statement

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```