# Django: Unable to add post in admin

Tags: python, django

Right now when I go  to admin and want to add post, I get this message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/blog/post/add/
Reverse for 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' not found. 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/blog/post/add/
Django Version: 3.2.9
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' not found. 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\mysite\\my_site',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\lib',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\Scripts',
 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python37-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 21 Dec 2021 17:36:13 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19

Reverse for 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' not found. 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
9               {% for field in line %}
10                  <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
11                      {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
12                      {% if field.is_checkbox %}
13                          {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
14                      {% else %}
15                          {{ field.label_tag }}
16                          {% if field.is_readonly %}
17                              <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
18                          {% else %}
19                              {{ field.field }}
20                          {% endif %}
21                      {% endif %}
22                      {% if field.field.help_text %}
23                          <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
24                      {% endif %}
25                  </div>
26              {% endfor %}
27          </div>
28      {% endfor %}
29  </fieldset>
```

Do you know what can be an issue?
you can find more details in my issue which is related to this one: [Django Unable to add WYSIWYG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70423227/django-unable-to-add-wysiwyg?noredirect=1#comment124513093_70423227)

Comment: Did you added urlpattern for summernote in project urls.py?

Comment: The [NoReverseMatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#noreversematch) error is saying that django cannot find a matching url pattern for the url.

Comment: I do not have it included, which line I should put there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added below to urls.py and page is working as never before :)

```
from django.urls import include
# ...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    ...
]
```